# Please assist me in resolving an Undefined offset: 0 in /public_html/wp-content/themes/modus-child/functions.php on line 51

Tags: php, html, undefined, offset

I have inherited a problematic website after communication broke-down with their original web developer.

I have been working through and resolving as many errors as possible.

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/customer/www/public_html/wp-content/themes/modus-child/functions.php on line 51

The long term goal will be to re-build the website, using a different theme, but I would appreciate some help in resolving this error to give us a safety net while the development is taking place.

[Screenshot showing the code as pasting the code didn't look right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjGfe.png)

here is line 46 onwards
Line 51 is the line that begins with if($featured[0]=="Featured"){
I can see the offset 0 in brackets.

```
$count=0;
      foreach ($woo_catgery as $sc) {
            $count++;
            if($count==6){continue;}
            $featured = get_field('featured', $sc->taxonomy . '_' . $sc->term_id);
            if($featured[0]=="Featured"){
            $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $sc->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image_url=wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
            if(!empty($image_url)){
                $image_url=$image_url;
            }else{$image_url=get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/blank.png';}
            $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
            $hm .='<li>
                    <div class="cat_image">
                        <a href="'. $link .'" title="" target="_self">        
                            <img alt="icon" src="'.$image_url.'">
                        </a>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat_bx_cnt">
                        <div class="cat_ttl">
                            <h3 class="cat_ttl_mn">'.$sc->name.'</h3>                      
                        </div>
                        <a class="link-more" href="'. $link .'" title="" target="_self">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>               
            '; 
            }
      }
      $hm .='</ul>';
      return $hm;
    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', '__return_empty_array' );

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_pgz_theme_support', 100 );

function remove_pgz_theme_support() { 
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

Comment: The error means, that `$featured` did not contain any element under an index/key `0`. We don’t know what kind of value the script is trying to read there, so we don’t know what `get_field` is _supposed_ to return here. It might have simply returned null, if no value was stored for that field in the first place – in that case, and if any of the further processing is to be skipped then, replacing that line with `if($featured && $featured[0]=="Featured")` could already do the trick.

Comment: Not a Wordpress guy, but from the manual `get_field()` returns a scalar value no an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$featured seems to be an empty array so you should first check if it contains elements:

```
if(count($featured) > 0 && $featured[0]=="Featured")
```

Comment: This answer needs no improvement. Thank you so very much!